# Multiple windows Live versions?

Tags: windows-7, windows-live

Today Steam asked me to do a little hardware and software survey and I thought, why not. After the survey you see the results. Most of it was pretty obvious except for this part:

```
 Συλλογή φωτογραφιών του Windows Live

 Основные компоненты Windows Live

 Почта Windows Live

 Фотоальбом Windows Live

 Фотогалерия на Windows Live

 גלריית התמונות של Windows Live

 بريد Windows Live

 معرض صور Windows Live
```

After searching a few of these on the internet I found out that they are pretty much different versions of Windows Live (at least I expect they are). There are versions in Hebrew, Greek and some other for me strange languages. My pc is now set to English (used to be Dutch) so I have no idea why they are on there.

If this really Windows Live or some virus or other bad software?

And is it possible to remove those things from my pc?

Comment: By "survey" what do you mean? You mean Steam created a list of all installed programs on your PC? Do you see all these versions of Windows Live listed under Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: Steam did make a list of all the installed programs on my PC, but I can't see them under Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: You can check for all those program versions under Program Files and Program Files (x86), but obviously phantom programs can't be uninstalled! Maybe Steam's detection routine is buggy...